# Wi-fi disconnects itself and the DNS changes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

My wi-fi disconnects itself.
When I am away from my PC for few minutes and get back to use the browser, I learn that the wi-fi disconnected.

How or why did this happen?
Also when I used the tracert command in cmd to check any changes, I found the ip address in the second line (after my router ip address) is changed.

This ip address in the second line used to change only when I turned off my router then turn back on.

But now this ip address changes when the wi-fi automatically disconnected.
My questions are:

1. Why wi-fi disconnected itself?
2. What does the second and third private ip address (tracert command) indicates?
3. Why did that second ip address (tracert command) changed after wi-fi reconnected?
4. Is it somebody hacking my wi-fi network?
5. Is it ISP problem?
   Here are the screenshots of the tracert command.

[image: tracert command output before wi-fi disconnected itself]

[image: tracert command output after wi-fi reconnected]

Comment: Who is 10.0.0 1 and whats your ipaddress.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Go to Google & type "what's my IP address?" Check it again after any outage. I'd suspect your ISP is using CGNAT [hence the 10.x.x.x pool] & isn't holding your DHCP lease as long as would seem sensible, meaning every glitch you get a new address. Next step - ring your ISP.

Comment: Can you use one of those "Wi-Fi scanner/analyzer" programs to check whether there are multiple APs with the same Wi-Fi network name? (Maybe you're connecting to neighbor's Wi-Fi?)

Comment: Yeah, a DHCP lease issue is also possible, but gateway IPs don't indicate CGNAT on their own, it's fairly common to route public addresses via privately-addressed gateways.

Comment: @RohitGupta - That's exactly what I wanted to know. The 10.0.0.1 and 10.0192.1 are private ip addresses. They change every time I turn off the router then turn back on.
The ip address 10.250.0.128 is always present on the third line. I don't know this one as well. Maybe they belong to the ISP or not.

Comment: @Community - I have my questions listed above.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I entered "ipconfig /all" command in the cmd and saw that the lease duration is one hour only. So, is it a problem?

Comment: @user1686 - I am using my own wi-fi which is hidden and it has different name than other present in my area.